# Weird representation of Turkish letters in URL

Tags: url, decode, urldecode

I have collected some data, which is encoded in URL and contains Turkish letters.

but what Turkish letter is %263287 or %23305?

Can someone give me a list of some sort? I could not find the corresponding letters in the internet

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the Turkish letter ğ is transferred to %26%23304%3B, but my decoding program decodes %26 and %3B, so I get &%23304; which seems pretty messed up.

Following this logic I have to decode the Turkish letters first.